# Would the two independent events be conditionally independent?

Tags: probability, bayesian, independence

Suppose we have a coin with bias $\theta$ within [0, 1]. If we define the outcome of flipping a coin as a random variable X with value in $\{0, 1\}$ and flip it twice (given $\theta$ known), would the following hold true?

$P(x_{1:2}=00 | \theta)=P(x_1=0|\theta)P(x_2=0|\theta)$, where $x_{1:2}$ as shorthand for the sequence $x_1, x_2$.

Comment: The events are conditionally independent but not unconditionally independent.

Comment: The question in the title is different from the question in the text.

Comment: @Xi'an - that looks like a Bayesian comment.  I agree with it, but it seems to make assumptions about the nature of $\theta$

Answer (score 2):

As also mentioned in the comments, the two tosses are independent only if we know the probability of head of the coin itself. Otherwise, the probability of head can be inferred from past outcomes (in this case there is only one) and the events are *dependent*, i.e. $P_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)\neq P_{X_1}(x_1)P_{X_2}(x_2)$.